# Get dynamic link url in ios of firebase dynamic link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When my app was not installed, and I install my app at first, I can get the dynamic link after installation.

But When my app was already installed, my app was launched directly, but I can't get the dynamic link.

How can I get the dynamic link url, when my app was installed?

Here is my swift code(AppDelegate.swift)

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // dynamic link
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            // Handle the deep link. For example, show the deep-linked content or
            // apply a promotional offer to the user's account.
            // ...
            handleIncoingDynamicLink(dynamicLink) //<-not fired
            return true
        }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            // Handle the deep link. For example, show the deep-linked content or
            // apply a promotional offer to the user's account.
            // ...
            print(dynamicLink)  //<-- not fired
            handleIncoingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)

            return true
        }

        let handled: Bool = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
        return handled
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. It were my mistakes.

Some interfaces of AppDelegate.swift was not same in between Swift4 and Swift5, and I was using Swift4 interface.

After matching the interface, It works well.